# Was I right in reviewing this answer as "Looks Good"?

Tags: discussion, support, review, low-quality-posts

I was reviewing [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4183124), which appeared to be wrong and quite short:

> What you need is the following on Ubuntu:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
> ```

Now [the question says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17915098/openssl-ssl-h-no-such-file-or-directory-during-installation-of-git):

> I do not have yum/apt-get on my machines

Though it's said that wrong answers shouldn't be deleted, it seems to be irrelevant to the question. However, I'm unsure that my action was correct, as 4 others had recommended that the answer be deleted. My question is, was this answer irrelevant, and should this answer have been deleted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion, the answer should be deleted. It's a perfect example of a low quality post. It seems to me that the user just read the title without reading anything else. I mean, the OP literally says:

**Q:** *"I do not have yum/apt-get on my machines..."*

And wait for it...

**A:** *"What you need... sudo apt-get install libssl-dev"*

Zero effort was made to understand the issue and those types of posts provide nothing useful to the Stack Exchange Network. So yes, it's irrelevant and should be deleted.

Comment: Thanks, previously I'd recommend deletion on most stuff but nowadays I'm more cautious because of some moderators saying that it's wrong to delete incorrect answers. Good to know that some answers are still poor enough to be deleted, flagged as very low quality.